# Show static rows one by one using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table

```
<table class="hTab">
     <tr class="hTr"> </tr>
     <tr class="hTr"> </tr>
     <tr class="hTr"> </tr>
</table>
<tr> <input type=button value="Show 1 more" id="onemore" /></tr>
```

I have used following jQuery code to show the rows one by one (I have declared 10 rows in the table)

```
var currentrow = 0;

$('#hTab #hTr').hide();
$('#hTab #tr:eq(0)').show();

$("#onemore").click(function () {
    currentrow++;
    $('#hTab #hTr:eq(' + currentrow + ')').show();
});
```

But at the moment it's not working. If anyone can show me the error in my code, it will be very helpful

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: `#` <-- points to an ID, while `.` <-- points to a class. So, it should be `.hTab .hTr` instead.

Comment: [How do I select an item using class or ID?](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-item-using-class-or-id/)

Comment: Your code has some syntax error! can you correct them pleas!

Comment: thx for ur helps. yeah i hv mistakenly put it as and class.

Answer (score 1):

You should use class selector `.` instead of id selector `#`, e.g :

```
$('.hTab .hTr:eq(' + currentrow + ')').show();
```

So the code will be :

```
var currentrow = 0;

$('.hTab .hTr').hide();
$('.hTab tr:eq(0)').show();

$("#onemore").click(function () {
    currentrow++;
    $('.hTab .hTr:eq(' + currentrow + ')').show();
});
```

**NOTE :** the button shouldn't be inside `tr` tag because it's outside of the table, and you have to add `td`s inside every `tr`.

Hope this helps.

```js
var currentrow=0;

$('.hTab .hTr').hide();
$('.hTab tr:eq(0)').show();

$("#onemore").click(function () {
  currentrow++;
  $('.hTab .hTr:eq(' + currentrow + ')').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="hTab">
  <tr class="hTr"><td> A </td></tr>
  <tr class="hTr"><td> B </td></tr>
  <tr class="hTr"><td> C </td></tr>
</table>
<input type=button value="Show 1 more" id="onemore" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`hTab` and `hTr` is class not a id:

so use everywhere:

```
$('.hTab .hTr')
```

```js
    var currentrow = 0;
    $('.hTab .hTr').hide();
    $('.hTab .hTr:eq(0)').show();

    $("#onemore").click(function () {
        currentrow++;
        $('.hTab .hTr:eq(' + currentrow + ')').show();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="hTab">
     <tr class="hTr"> <td>A<td> </tr>
     <tr class="hTr"> <td>B<td> </tr>
     <tr class="hTr"> <td>C<td> </tr>
</table>
<tr> <input type=button value="Show 1 more" id="onemore" /></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

please see the fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/htoniv/wrydcd2o/)

```
var currentrow = 0;

    $('.hTab .hTr').hide();
    $('.hTab tr:eq(0)').show();

    $("#onemore").click(function () {
        currentrow++;
        $('.hTab .hTr:eq(' + currentrow + ')').show();
    });
```